# Prevent Wordpress from sending Cache-control http header

Tags: cache, http, varnish

My site sits on a server that uses Varnish as a (powerful) caching engine.
Unfortunately, it seems wordpress is busting the Varnish cache by sending a cache-control http header. If I `curl -I domain.com` I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.4.10
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=e00738aoughg407ljm270kj0l6; path=/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 21:44:16 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
```

I have other wordpress sites hosted on this server, which work correctly with the Varnish server, so I'm pretty sure the problem is caused by this specific installation. Here is what I tried:

- disable all plugins. Empty Varnish cache, then `curl -I`: same result.
- looked through all my theme files. Nothing suspicious.

Do you have any other idea as to what may cause the problem?

Comment: From quick search I cannot find a single instance of `no-store` being used in core. I doubt this is coming from WP itself.

Comment: As Rarst notes, no-store isn't used, but if it's helpful for other people WP will send no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0 and a few others for *logged in users*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @chrisguitarguy's answer, you can control the http headers sent by Wordpress via the "send_headers" hook. Here is the function I added to my theme's functions.php file, and that solved the issue with the Varnish server.

```
function varnish_safe_http_headers() {
    header( 'X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1' );
    session_cache_limiter('');
    header("Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=120");
  if( !session_id() )
  {
    session_start();
  }
}
add_action( 'send_headers', 'varnish_safe_http_headers' );
```

Comment: this starts a php session - which means varnish will never cache.

Answer (score 6):

You can hook into `wp_headers` and remove the cache control headers. WordPress generally doesn't send `Cache-Control` except for admin area or ajax requests, however.

```
add_filter('wp_headers', 'wpse167128_nocache');
function wpse167128_nocache($headers)
{
    unset($headers['Cache-Control']);
    return $headers;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Do you know if it will override any further  http header (re)writing by third party plugins?

Comment: In fact, the proper hook is "send_headers". Will post the final solution as an answer.

Comment: @pixeline wp_headers and send_headers are both valid hooks...the original question seems like a valid use case for wp_headers. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/.